# Dynamic Table row with Default Row When Model Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create a table that can populate dynamic rows, also I'm trying to populate single default raw when model is null

Model properties

```
public class UsrViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<User> SysUser { get; set; }
}

Public class User
{            
     public int ID {get; set:}
     public string user {get; set:}
     .. 
}
```

Controller methods

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Users()
    {
        try
        {

            IList<Users> listofusers = ..

            var model = new UsrViewModel
            {
                SysUser = listofsensors
            };

            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Users(IEnumerable<UsrViewModel> model)
    {
        try
        {
            ...

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

View page

```
@model ProjectName.ViewModels.UsrViewModel
    @{
    }
    <div class="content-page">

        <div class="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Users", "Sample", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="SysUser ">
                                        <tr>
                                           ...
                                        </tr>

                                        @if (Model != null)
                                        {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < Model.SysUser.Count; i++)
                                            {
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    [i]
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UsrViewModel[i].user , new { @type = "text", @class = "", @placeholder = "user Name", @required = "" })
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UsrViewModel[i].user, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                               </td>
                                                ....

                                            </tr>
                                            }
                                        }

                                    </table>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple waves-effect waves-light btn-wd-130">Save</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-light btn-wd-130">Clear</button>
                                </div>                 
                        }
                    </div>
                    <!-- end row -->

                </div> 
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

But this is not populating single default row when model is null , and can't add new rows dynamically. what should I change here?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using the `BeginCollectionItem()` method the wrong way. It needs to be applied to a single object. Its purpose is to modify the html to add collection indexers (based on a `Guid`) and add a hidden input for the indexer, which allows you to generate the html for objects in a collection and allow you to dynamically add (and remove) items to the collection.

Start by creating a partial view (say) `_User.cshtml` that generates a table row for a user

```
@model User
<tr>
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("SysUser")) // the parameter is the name of your collection property
    {
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.user)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.user)
        <td>
        <td>
            .... // form controls for other properties of user
        </td>
    }
</tr>
```

Then in the main view, use `Partial()` to generate the html for each `User` in the collection

```
@model UsrViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <thead>....</thead>
        <tbody id="users">
            @foreach (var user in Model.SysUser)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_User", user)
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
}
```

The only reason to use the `BeginCollectionItem()` is to be able to dynamically add and/or remove items from the collection in the view, so assuming you have an 'Add' button, you would handle its `.click()` event to call a server method that returns a partial view for a new `User` and append it to the table, for example

```
<button id="add" type="button">Add New User</button>

var url = '@Url.Action("NewUser")';
var users = $('#users');
$('#add').click(function () {
    $.get(url, function (html) {
        users.append(html);
    });
});
```

when your controller method is

```
public PartialViewResult NewUser()
{
    return PartialView("_User, new User());
}
```

You might also include a 'Delete' button in each row, so that you can handle its click event to call a server method that deletes the user from the database, and in the ajax success callback, remove the row from the table.

Comment: ur approch compile without any runtime or compile time errors  , not populate default row when no items , when I debug `@foreach (var user in Model.SysUser)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_User", user)
            }` this I can see after for loop its going to `@RenderBody();` in _Layout page

Comment: What do your mean? You don't (and should not) have a 'default' row - you add new rows by clicking the 'Add' button

Comment: I meant when this pageload (initial load) Its not populate any row , is that possible to do ?

Comment: You mean its not populating your existing users? If there are no existing users, then you add a row to your table using the add button (you do not add a default empty row initially - that would screw up validation)

Comment: yes if I dont have any user, is that possible to do without "add New user" button , when User Page initial Load can I invoke `"_User", new User()` ?

in here `[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Users()
    {` ?

Comment: You can always add a new user to your `SysUser` property in the GET method before you pass the model to the view. `var model = new UsrViewModel(){ SysUser = new List<User>() { new User() } }; return View(model);` - but that's crazy - what if the user does not edit that row - they would net even be able to submit assuming you have client side validation enabled

Comment: And what if the user wants to add 2 or more users - you need the 'Add' button. If you not going to have that then using the `BeginCollectionItem` is pointless - you may as well have a link to a age which creates a new `User`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128129/discussion-between-kez-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: How to get these values to post method. like this `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Users(UsrViewModelr sample)
        {` or `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Users(IEnumerable<User> sample)
        {` ??

Comment: It needs to be `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Users(UsrViewModel sample)`

Comment: but then `sample.SysUser` getting null but when I use exactly like this `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Users(IEnumerable<User> SysUser) {` its values binding

Comment: `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Users(UsrViewModel sample)` will work just fine unless you have other issues with your code (such as `UsrViewModel` contains a property named `sample`)

Comment: If I'm binding dropdown values in above partial view , when I click to add new row , its not working , 

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserCode, new SelectList(ViewBag.Users, "value", "name"), "Select the user"` so bind these viewbag properties , do I have to use Sessions ?

Comment: @kez Comments are not to be used for follow-up questions. This discussion will be tough for future visitors to follow and understand. Ask a new question if you have a new problem, or update your original question if it's in the same scope.

Comment: @kez, I can't guess what you code is or what `ViewBag.Users` is. Ask a new question with the relevant code (and no, you do not and should not use `Session`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke When I click Add new Row, currently its not create new row, do I need save current editing row to before add new row , in this approach ?

Comment: No. The code have shown will work fine (assuming the `NewUser()` method is in the same controller (if not then use `var url = '@Url.Action("NewUser", "yourControllerName")';`. What if any errors are you getting in the browser console when you click the button

Comment: This is my approach exactly , https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/444b9 how to bind dropdowns without viewbags to partial view, in your suggested approach ? without using viewbags

Comment: You have to set `ViewBag.Users = ???;` in the `NewUser()` method :) But if would be far better to have a property for the `SelectList` in the `User` model and initialize a new instance of `User` and set the value of that property before passing the model to the partial (and I assume you have now resolved the 'Add' button?)

Comment: And you can remove setting the `ViewBag.Users` in the `User()` method (its not used in the main view - its only used by the partial)

Comment: Lets go back into the [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128129/discussion-between-kez-and-stephen-muecke) :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ohh I forgot terribly , Nope when I click Add button this is wht happening http://imgur.com/sEO2YnJ